# SignalFX detector data().count() based on condition

Tags: splunk, signalfx

Is it possible to implement count() MTS based on condition?

For instance:
We need to monitor the amount of time RDS CPU picks the point of 95% for the last 3 days.

```
A = data('CPU_Utilization').count(...when point > 95%). 
detector(when(A > {number_of_times_breached}, lasting='3d')).publish(...)
```

Update.

Solution was found by my colleague:

```
A = data('CPU_Utilization').above({condition_value}, inclusive=True).count(...)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to evaluate a condition in signalfx too, were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/8.2.2203/Search/Usestatswithevalexpressionsandfunctions) with boolean result inside `count()` in your `SPL` query.

Something like

```
| <your search> | stats count(eval(point>0.95))
```

Comment: approach is good, but i can't find any reference from documentation to eval() function. Could you share one, pls?

Comment: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/8.2.2203/Search/Usestatswithevalexpressionsandfunctions

Comment: i see, sadly this function is a part of splunk query, but not sfx plugin. i found another approach, will update the post with a solution if will be needed one day.

Comment: Add your own solution as an answer and accept it.